# Looping in 2D Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, 2d

Please help me. im going crazy with this question. can anyone teach me? i suck at looping for 2D array..
 my question is : How can i loop answers produced by a 9 by 9 multiplication table and populating the answers into a 2D Array

Comment: can u show what u have done?

Comment: dont post whole your question in question title ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$multiplicant=9;
for($i=1;i<10;i++)
{
  $product[$i][$multiplicant] = $multiplicant*$i;

}
print_r($product);
```

Comment: please do me a favour by explaining?

Comment: @PheeYongXiang Yong Xiang actually yo u have to know how a for loop works and php arrays.which section you are not clear?

Comment: the for loops.. theyre quite complicated

Comment: each time the loop execute the value of i is incremented and the value of i is multiplied with 9 ans stored in an array whose index is (1,9)(2,9)(3,9).....(9,9) check here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < 9; $j++){
        $arr[$i][$j] = ($i + 1) * ($j + 1);
    }
}
```

Say that `$i` is the row of your multiplication table, and `$j` is the column.

In PHP arrays are 0-based, that is the first entry of an array is 0.

So we walk through each coordinate from 0 to 9 (`$ix$j`), filling each cell of the array with the result of the multiplication (we add 1 to `$i` and `$j` so that the 0th row contains the 1 multiplication table, and so on).

Maybe you should read some programming book before going on, because this is seally the basics.

Comment: Okay... could you re-explain the last part at the array part? i dont seem to quite understand.. thanks anyway!

Comment: could you give me some recommendation?